# How i reopen my google developer account again?

Tags: google-play-console, google-developers-console

Are There any way to recover my account?

[image]

Comment: This is a customer service question and is thus off-topic here. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/14853083)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to your email as there will be more details regarding the account closure. However, dormant (inactive, abondoned) accounts are considered to violate Google Play Developer agreement and are terminated for life. They cannot be claimed back and/or developer account payment will not be refunded. You may possibly open another account with new email:

> Closure of a dormant account will not limit your ability to create a
> new account in the future if you decide to publish on Google Play. You
> will not be able to reactivate your account and any previous apps or
> data will not be available on a new account.

Check [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9899234) for more details.